# Adding lateral information to table

Tags: html, css

I want to had some information to the left side ( Where I drew something ) of my table, like in this image:

[image]

But I don't know how. Is it part of the table? Do I need to create a new table? Help would be appreciated

**UPDATE**
Sorry, didn't explained well. I want the table to have an extra slot on the left side, to separate the morning, afternoon and night, but I don't know if it's with the table or creating a separated div, something like [This](http://holmesplace.pt/holmes-place-health-club-braga-ginasio-fitness-musculacao-spa-saude-emagrecer-dieta-zumba.c/pt/schedule/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge cells with `rowspan` and create blank spaces with `empty-cells: hide`.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
   empty-cells: hide;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```